# Gradient of a function at specific x,y,z values in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm looking for a way to find the gradient of a function and then evaluate the output at specific x,y,z values. Thus far, I have

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Clear[x, y, z]
v1 = Grad[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 9, Cartesian[x, y, z]]
```

which outputs 
    {2 x, 2 y, 2 z}. How could I  evaluate this at x=2,y=2, and z=1, for instance? This seems trivial for the function above, but it would be immensely useful for more complicated functions. Thank you very much for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `Replace` the variables by values using `Rule`:

`v1/.{x->2,y->2,z->1}`